# При запуске jar-файла получаю ошибку java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java, xml, maven, jar, локализация

Мне нужно использовать локализацию в моем проекте, вот его структура.
[image: структура]

С помощью Maven я собираю два jar файла - сервер и клиентскую часть вот так.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.itmo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Lab8</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>server-main</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>server-main</finalName>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>com.itmo.server.ServerMain</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>client-main</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>client-main</finalName>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>com.itmo.client.MainConsole</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Когда я запускаю из Идеи всё работает. Однако при запуске джарников появляется ошибка.

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name locals, locale ru
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at com.itmo.utils.LocaleClass.<init>(LocaleClass.java:14)
        at com.itmo.server.ServerMain.<clinit>(ServerMain.java:11)
```

Я использую данный класс при работе с локалями.

```java
import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LocaleClass {
    @Getter
    public ResourceBundle resourceBundle;

    public LocaleClass(){
         resourceBundle = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle("locals", Locale.forLanguageTag("RU"), new UTF8Control());
    }

    public LocaleClass(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.resourceBundle = resourceBundle;
    }

    public void changeLocale(Locale locale){
        resourceBundle = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle("locals", locale, new UTF8Control());
    }

    public enum SupportedLanguages{
        RU,
        EST,
        SPA,
        SWE
    }


    public void changeLocaleByTag(String TAG){
        changeLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(TAG));
    }
    public void changeLocaleByTag(SupportedLanguages TAG){
        changeLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(TAG.toString()));
    }

    public String getString(String text){
        return resourceBundle.getString(text);
    }
}
```

Я не очень хорошо понимаю, что происходит, почему не находит мои локали и как это исправить, хоть и гуглил.

UPD: добавил дерево каталогов jar

[image: jar]

Comment: Покажите дерево каталогов jar - скорее всего в jar не включены ресурсы.

Comment: @Barmaley обновил

Comment: jar вроде собран правильно. У меня если честно нет идей. Надо отлаживать. Я бы начал с того, что завел `locals.properties` по умолчанию, вырубил параметр `Locale` и `ResourceBundle.Control`...

Comment: @Barmaley я создал locals.properties и скопировал туда содержимое locals_RU.properties, jar запускаются, но теперь не работает смена языка...

Comment: Ну вот - уже теплее, значит проблема не в поиске `Bundle` внутри jar - там все верно. Проблема в именовании ресурсных файликов, возможно в `Locale.forLanguageTag()`...

Answer (score 0):

Помогла смена регистра в имени файлов: locals_RU.properties -> locals_ru.properties.